# Catalyst: Download Logfile securely

Tags: web-services, perl, web-applications, logging, catalyst

I have the following problem:

my Catalyst Webservice uses Log4Perl to generate a logfile which logs all user activities.

How can i provide this file as download only for admins? The root directory is no option, because everybody could download it. I need a secure way. Admins have a separate area within the webservice to manage the users.

Using ssh / sftp is unfortunately also no option, the log has to be available over the webservice.

Comment: How do you ensure that admins only can access that separate area?

Comment: Admins have a separate login mask und the created session is different, this is no problem and works fine

Comment: Why don't you just use that session in a log-file-sending action to authenticate admins? :)

Comment: And how do i create this log-file-sending action????
I tried something, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, i was really busy the last few days.
Thanks for your help, thats the solution i have built and it works :-)

```
sub log : Chained('base_admin') PathPart('log') Args(0) {
    my ( $self, $c ) = @_;
    my $logfile = $c->path_to('test.log');

    $c->response->header('Content-Type' => 'text/plain');
    $c->response->header('Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename=test.log');
    $c->serve_static_file($logfile);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To build a log-file-sending action as @memowe suggested, you will need a controller that does the following things:

1. Verify the logged-in user is an admin, and redirect if not.
2. Create a scalar `$filehandle` to read the log-file.
3. Use `$c->res->content_type(something)` and `$c->res->header('Content-Disposition' => 'attachment')` to force the response to be treated as a download for the browser to present the "Save As..." dialog.
4. Set `$c->res->body($filehandle)` to return the contents of the log-file and bypass your View renderer (Template or whatever).

Hopefully that should get you on your way.